# Calculate $12345 \pmod{11}$ and $12345\times 98765 \pmod{11}$ by hand.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know the answers to those questions, but I'd like to know how to do them by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$10 \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$$

You might like to write $12345=10000+2000+300+40+5$.

Comment: So getting that 10000(mod 11) is 1, 2000(mod 11) is 9, 300(mod 11) is 3, 40(mod 11) is 7, 5(mod 11) is 5, which is 25 altogether, and 25(mod 11) is 3?

Comment: yup, try to work with smaller number, we can write $9$ as $-2$ in mod $11$. Hence the question is just $1-2+3-4+5\equiv 3 \pmod{11}$

Comment: I see, and you would do the same with $12345 \times 98765$?

Comment: Similar trick applies. note that $ab \pmod{c} \equiv (a \pmod{c}) (b \pmod{c}) $. Try to work with small numbers. don't multiply two $5$-digit numbers.